OpenVpn configuration problem - how to access to vpn client subnet on vpn server
I have a problem with configuring OpenVpn connection. I want to configure a virtual machine to have something like hub of other vpn's. On virtual machine (lubuntu) I have a few OpenVpn clients and it works. I have foo example 192.168.10.0/24 and 192.168.11.0/24. On the same virtual machine I have OpenVpn server able to connect.
On other computer I have client OpenVpn - and I am able to connect, but I am not able to get 192.168.10/24 and 192.168.11.0/24 subnets access.
I tried pushing that subnets to openvpn - but with no results.
push "route 192.168.11.0 255.255.255.0" not works. I have access (ping) to another virtual adapter IP on vm, but I can not get to subnets from other vpn's.
Can I ask for help?
Jannas1
